# How to deal with shared library problems in a non-working package

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, dns, dependencies

I installed bind-tools, the Arch linux alternative to dnsutils, but none of the tools work, all failing with the error:

```
host: error while loading shared libraries: libidn2.so.4: cannot open shared object files: No such file or directory
```

This problem with libidn2.so.4 seems to be a recent issue (January 2019) with Arch package builds and has apparently produced [some pretty scary results, like making the entire system unbootable](https://labs.parabola.nu/issues/2139).

My questions are: (1) is the right approach to just wait until the maintainer of bind-tools fixes this problem, or to try to fix it myself? and (2) what exactly is going on? bind-tools requires libidn2.so.4 but does not install it? How could the maintainers possibly make such an error?

Comment: I have Arch Linux in my lab but I'm not able to reproduce your issue after having updated today. The symlinks `/usr/lib/libidn2.so` and `/usr/lib/libidn2.so.4` exist pointing to `/usr/lib/libidn2.so.4.0.0`. All of the tools such `nslookup` and `dig` are working with no issue. If you `ll /usr/lib/libidn2` and hit tab, does it return the actual library `libidn2.so.4.0.0`?. If so, you can just create the symlink yourself as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: @NasirRiley My system does not have 4.0.0 on it, so if it is a dependency of bind-tools, then it is missing from the install because it did not get installed. My system has .0.3.4 on it

Comment: @Nasir Riley Please never recommend `-Syy` ever again, as it is dangerous and can and will break your system, both because of the lack of `-u` and because of the presence a double `-yy`. See the warning here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mirrors#Force_pacman_to_refresh_the_package_lists

Comment: @eschwartz I don't mean this as a personal attack, but it should be apparent that `-Syy` was a typo. I got the command from that same link that you suggested and I just left out the `uu` so I've already read it. I'm a human being who is prone to typos like everyone else.

Comment: Run pacman -Q libidn. If it's returning a version earlier than 1.35.1, run pacman -Syyuu to synchronize the package database and then pacman -S libidn to install the latest version which will provide libidn2.so.4.0.0

Comment: It is not apparent -- the internet is literally full of the advice to use -Sy or -Syy, and a typo which is also a valid command which happens to be dangerous, is statistically not going to be a typo.

Comment: @eschwartz Yes, it is apparent. A typo can very easily be a valid command so you aren't making any sense there at all. What isn't apparent is your comment which links to an entire page full of many different things instead of just saying precisely what you mean and explaining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't run Arch Linux, so I'm going out on a limb a bit on this.

The article you linked to indicates it's a missing symbolic link, rather than a missing package.  This makes sense, because normally in Linux, shared libraries will have at least two octets of version number after the '.so', and the error only mentions one.

My suggestion is that you run

```
ls -l /usr/lib/libidn2.so*
```

and see what it returns.  If it just returns

```
/usr/lib/libidn2.so
```

and doesn't mention anything more specific, then I would recommend running

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libidn2.so /usr/lib/libidn2.so.0
ln -s /usr/lib/libidn2.so /usr/lib/libidn2.so.4
```

I'm suggesting running both, because it seems your program is looking for major version four of the library, but the article you referenced is looking for major version zero.  This fix basically makes two aliases to the file /usr/lib/libidn2.so, one with a .0 and one with a .4.

If you see that there's a /usr/lib/libidn2.so.something.something, and the /usr/lib/libidn2.so is a symlink to it, it may make more sense to symlink to the more specific file.  I don't really know which way would necessarily be best.

Another option for you would be to downgrade your libidn2 to the one before this issue.

As far as how this could happen - it looks like the maintainer of libidn2 for Arch Linux made a mistake.  What baffles me is not that this happened at all but... that bug was added 12 days ago.  A bug that can just be fixed with some manual symbolic links should take hours to fix, not weeks.  I do not mean to disparage the Arch Linux maintainers; I have no idea what is happening on their side of things.  It's just... frustrating.  My guess is that this is just the tip of the iceberg of this story.  In any case, people are people, and we all make mistakes.  Somebody is probably already beating themselves up over this, and they don't need our help to do it.

Comment: I created that link and the tools worked, so I guess the existing so (which is libidn2.so.0.3.4) is just as good as libidn2.so.0.4 or maybe it was a typo omitting the .3?

Comment: That could be.  Or it's possible that the package used an automated linkage that assumed there would only be two numbers in released code, and it tried to link to libidn2.so.0.3 and didn't find it.  Exactly how this happened isn't truly important to us; it's just something the Arch Linux maintainers need to work out and determine how to avoid.  We're getting by for another day, that's good enough for us.

Comment: Firstly, using ln to make a library that *is not compatible* and whose soname changed because it *is not compatible*, pretend to be compatible anyway, is a truly terrible idea as the application will load code which is silently corrupted and can do anything without warning. Second, nice assumption that Arch Linux maintainers broke anything, but have you even considered the possibility that it *may* have been user error? Telling users to blame someone else is fun, but isn't very productive, and it also makes for terrible answers.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the sort of error that comes up a lot in Arch Linux, I've written a specialized script to analyze packages and determine if they are correctly built. (In 95% of cases the Arch Linux package is correctly built): https://github.com/eli-schwartz/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/pkg-list-linked-libraries

Running this on the bind-tools package and looking for libidn2 shows that the latest version of bind-tools is linked to libidn.so.4:

```
$ pkg-list-linked-libraries bind-tools libidn2
==> checking linked libraries for bind-tools-9.13.5-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz ...
/usr/bin/dig
  NEEDED               libidn2.so.4
/usr/bin/host
  NEEDED               libidn2.so.4
/usr/bin/nslookup
  NEEDED               libidn2.so.4
```

Where does that library come from?

```
$ pacman -Qo /usr/lib/libidn2.so.4
/usr/lib/libidn2.so.4 is owned by libidn2 2.1.0-1
```

The bind-tools package in Arch requires the libidn2 package as a dependency, according to the output of `pacman -Si bind-tools`, which is well and good since it depends on it.

The versions of the two packages in the official Arch Linux repositories at the time of this writing correspond to the version of bind-tools and libidn2 that I've checked above:

```
$ expac -S '%n %v' libidn2 bind-tools
libidn2 2.1.0-1
bind-tools 9.13.5-4
```

So, you plainly have the latest version of bind-tools installed. But you claim you don't have the libidn2 libraries the binaries require. Why not? What is your version of libidn2 that is currently installed? Check the output of `pacman -Q libidn2`.

Since the package works for thousands of other people, my conclusion is that your system is broken, and you need to properly update your system in order to install the latest version of libidn2. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported for details on why this might happen, what to do to properly fix it, and why symlinking is not only not the solution, but will break your system even further.

As for the Parabola bug, that is the exact opposite problem. A completely different Linux distribution that is *not* Arch Linux, failed to rebuild their packages using the new libidn2, and as a result those packages were erroneously linking to libidn2.so.0

If you're really suffering from that Parabola bug, then you're not using Arch Linux at all, and you need to specify that you're actually using Parabola, because otherwise people won't know how to help you.

Comment: When I do pacman -Q libidn2 it results in libidn2 2.0.5-1. I don't understand why I need to upgrade my system (which already was done two weeks ago). If a package has a dependency, shouldn't it be doing any necessary upgrades for those dependencies?

Comment: Again, Arch Linux does not support partial updates. This is a matter of policy, so it doesn't matter whether other Linux distributions support upgrading the dependencies of a package when doing partial updates -- if you want a distro that supports that, use the other distro which supports that.